# Как настроить сборку одного билда webpack

Tags: webpack

Сейчас у меня настроен webpack и по команде npm run build собирается два билда, один для сайта, второй для админки.

Хотелка моя в том, чтобы за раз я мог делать билд чего-то одного, либо сайта, либо админки.
Одновременная сборка занимает продолжительное время

webpack.config.js содержит следующее

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

var config = {
    module: {},
};

var plugins = [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'build.css'
        })
    ];

var main_app_config = Object.assign({}, config, {

    entry: ["@babel/polyfill", './src/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/public_html/dist'),
        filename: 'build.js',
        library: 'App',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: plugins,

});

var admin_app_config = Object.assign({}, config, {

    entry: ["@babel/polyfill", './src/index_admin.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/public_html/admin_2/dist'),
        filename: 'build.js',
        library: 'App',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: plugins,

});

module.exports = [main_app_config, admin_app_config];
```

Answer (score 0):

В вызове вебпака можно указать флаг `--config <путь к файлу>`. Он позволяет указать вебпаку, какой именно файл конфигурации нужно использовать для сборки.

Таким образом вы можете в package.json указать два скрипта для запуска webpack с разными файлами конфигурации. А сами файлы создать разделив имеющийся на два. Думаю с этим разберетесь уже сами. :)